# Xcode 13 quick help window not launch on custom objects

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode13

Ever since I downloaded Xcode 13 I have been unable to see the quick help window (option click) for objects/functions/variables I have created.

I can see the quick help window for other swift frameworks (option clicking tableView works, for example). Just not for my own.

I have tried

- running this in command line:

```sh
$ defaults delete com.apple.dt.Xcode WebKitJavaScriptEnabled
```

- deleting this:

```sh
~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode
```

- running this:

```sh
$ defaults delete com.apple.dt.Xcode IDEIndexDisable
```

This is what I see when I run:

```sh
$ cd ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DocumentationCache/
$ ls -al
total 0
drwxr-xr-x   4 myname  staff  128 Sep 21 13:13 .
drwxr-xr-x  13 myname  staff  416 Sep 24 20:38 ..
drwxr-xr-x   3 myname  staff   96 Apr 28 10:49 v187
drwxr-xr-x   3 myname  staff   96 Sep 21 13:13 v202
```

Anyone know of any fixes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A **restart** of the machine solved the issue for me. Xcode then installed components and built the quick help for Apple's documentation and the documentation in my own code.

Comment: Well, I tried this several times before reading your comment. I tried again after reading your comment, and it worked. Thank you, magic stack overflow user

Comment: worked for me too.... weird